# How to switch between array data with the angular translate plugin

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic project with the plugin [angular translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) from Pascal Precht. I am able to translate stuff like the title in the view etc. But I need to translate my content and this is where I am a bit lost.

So I have 2 arrays (one in English and the other in Dutch), the array looks like this (each array has 14 object in them - for the purpose of this explanation i will just show 1 object in the array):

```
gin_mixes: [
            {
                id: '1',
                title: 'Bathtub Gin Mix',
                src: 'img/placeholder-bathtub-gin-colored.png',
                backdrop: 'img/backdrop_bathtub-gin.jpg',
                lang: 'en',
                ingredients: [
                    {
                        ingred1: 'Bathtub Gin - 5 cl',
                        ingred2: 'Cardamom - 2 pcs',
                        ingred3: 'Clove - 3 pcs',
                        ingred4: 'Orange wedges - 2 pcs'
                    }
                ],
                picturesIngred : [
                    {
                        pictIng1: 'img/bathtub-gin.jpg',
                        pictIng2: 'img/kardemon.jpg',
                        pictIng3: 'img/kruidnagels.jpg',
                        pictIng4: 'img/orange-wedges.jpg',
                    }
                ],
                tonics: [
                    {
                        tonic1: 'Fever Tree Premium Indian Tonic',
                        tonic2: 'Indi Tonic',
                        tonic3: 'Schweppes Premium Tonic Water',
                        tonic4: 'Thomas Henry Tonic Water'
                    }
                ],
                pictureTonics: [
                    {
                        pictTonic1: 'img/fever-tree.jpg',
                        pictTonic2: 'img/indie-tonic.jpg',
                        pictTonic3: 'img/schweppes-premium.jpg',
                        pictTonic4: 'img/thomas-henry.jpg',
                    }
                ],
                utensils: [
                    {
                        utens1: 'Measuring cup',
                        utens2: 'Spoon',
                        utens3: 'Peeler',
                        utens4: 'Pestle'
                    }
                ],
                recipe: [
                    {
                        step1: 'Fill a glass with ice cubes',
                        step2: 'Add the orange wedges together with the 3 pieces of clove in the glass together with 2 mashed cardamons ',
                        step3: 'Poor 5 cl of Bathtub Gin into the glass',
                        step4: 'And lastly add 20 cl of tonic to the mix'
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

In my settings view I give the user the option to switch between English and Dutch. When the user chooses for example Dutch then my app changes languages and I can see my translated changes (title in view etc).

But what I now need is to know is how to dynamically change the content with my 2 arrays. So if the user choose English as the language then the content has to show up in english (content from array).

I am NOT working with an external json file. The array I implemented in my service like so:

```
.service('GinTonicService', function($q){
    return {
        gin_mixes_en: [
            {
                id: '1',
                ...
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                ....
            },

        ],
        gin_mixes_nl: [
            {
                id: '1',
                ...
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                ....
            },

        ],
        getGinMixesEN: function(){
            return this.gin_mixes_en;
        },
        getGinMixByIdEN: function(id){
            var d = $q.defer();

            this.gin_mixes_en.forEach(function(ginmix) {
                if (ginmix.id === id) d.resolve(ginmix);
            })

            return d.promise;
        },
        getGinMixesNL: function(){
            return this.gin_mixes_nl;
        },
        getGinMixByIdNL: function(id){
            var d = $q.defer();

            this.gin_mixes_nl.forEach(function(ginmix) {
                if (ginmix.id === id) d.resolve(ginmix);
            })

            return d.promise;
        }
    }

});
```

Now I am able to read out the content in english like so (part of my html view):

```
<div class="list card padding">
        <h4 class="p_benodigdheden" translate='utensils'></h4>
        <br>
        <div class="custom_list" ng-repeat="utensils in getGinMixById.utensils">
            <ul>
                <li>{{utensils.utens1}}</li>
                <li>{{utensils.utens2}}</li>
                <li>{{utensils.utens3}}</li>
                <li ng-hide="!utensils.utens4.length">{{utensils.utens4}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand correctly your problem.
If in your service is also available gin_mixes_nl: [], you can define a function that set all $scope objects fields, that have localized strings, with the values of gin_mixes_nl: [].

Comment: @ronIDX:hi thanks for the fast replay, but i don't understand what your saying.

Comment: I mean something like this: [Translate with service](http://codepen.io/grimaldello/pen/wMYeeJ?editors=1011). All translations are already in the service.

Comment: @ronIDX, should i not be doing it with the plugin from pascal preach - angular translate (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) ?

Comment: I used it in some of my projects, and it's good for translations. But you need to structure your translations differently from your actual configuration, and put mostly in .config(). Take a look at this example using pascal preach: [Pascal Preach](http://jsfiddle.net/PascalPrecht/eUGWJ/4/)

Comment: I use my method for translations, when the translated strings come from a web service, so they are already translated and I have only to show them (that's similar to your case, where you have all your translated strings in a service). In all other cases I use pascal plugin

Comment: @ronIDX: do you know how to dynamical inject data into the translate file -> https://gyazo.com/328c8e7a31a4d8d98f0bb73247f5dec5

Comment: Yep you have to define it like in this example: [Angular Translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)

Comment: @ronIDX, mmm dit is not what i mean. this i already know ;-). i mean injecting two way binding into translation file